# Liferay scheduler is not firing on clustering

Tags: liferay, quartz-scheduler, liferay-6, weblogic-10.x

I had scheduler used in portlet which will be triggering for each 5 minutes.

following are the configurations:
liferay-portlet.xml:

```
<scheduler-entry>
  <scheduler-description>
   This scheduler is used to invoke the update and delete results
  </scheduler-description>
 <scheduler-event-listener-class>com.test.myown.scheduler.action.GetResultsScheduler</scheduler-event-listener-class>
  <trigger>
     <simple>
        <simple-trigger-value>5</simple-trigger-value>
        <time-unit>minute</time-unit>
      </simple>
  </trigger>
</scheduler-entry>
```

And my class is :

```
  public class GetResultsScheduler implements MessageListener{
     public void receive(Message message) throws MessageListenerException {
         // some code here
     }
  }
```

we are using liferay 6.1,weblogic server
Here the problem is, There are 2 nodes for server ,
Scheduler is triggering for 5 minutes in node1
There is no scheduler triggering in node 2

What I meant say is, scheduler is working in node 1 and not working in node2.

Can any one have any idea about this issue?

Comment: Another great example of duplicate work being generated by unlinked crossposts. Sigh! https://www.liferay.com/en_GB/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/57470411

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is expected: When you run some frequent jobs, you might not want to execute them concurrently on each machine, as they'll get in conflict. You've stated that the job must be executed every 5 minutes, not twice every 5 minutes (as it would be if every machine would fire it).

If you take down node1, I'd also expect node2 to take over the duty of executing the scheduled jobs. This will be a good test for the correctness of the assumption stated above.

Also, you shouldn't rely on such jobs to execute in each VM (probably manipulating common state, shared through the classloader). If you modify content that is cached, the cluster communication should take care to invalidate the classes.

If you have problems with this, you're either violating that (my) assumption of the global state in the VM, or you've not configured the cluster cache invalidation correctly.